# Scipy.optimize.newton for complex valued function

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to find a root using [scipy.optimize.newton](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html) for a complex valued function. The function works great when I pass the derivative of the function as one of the arguments thus the Newton-Raphson method is used, however when I do not pass the derivative and try to use the secant method with only one inital guess (it works if a second inital guess is passed thus the problematic line is skipped), it generates the following error:

```
# I understand the error I was just wondering if there's a workaround.
x, r = optimize.newton(f_complex, x0=complex(5, -2), tol=1e-9, full_output=True)

# Error
File "C:\...\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\zeros.py", line 325, in newton
p1 += (eps if p1 >= 0 else -eps)
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'int'
```

This is what I've tried:

```
from scipy import optimize

def f(z):
    return z**2 + 1 

def fp(z):
    return 2 * z

# works
x, r = x, r = optimize.newton(f, x0=complex(5, -2), fprime=fp, tol=1e-9, full_output=True)
print(r)

# does not work
x, r = x, r = optimize.newton(f, x0=complex(5, -2), tol=1e-9, full_output=True)
print(r)

#  works if I pass a second initial guess thus line #325 is skipped
x, r = x, r = optimize.newton(f, x0=complex(5, -2), tol=1e-9, full_output=True, x1=complex(4, -1.5))
print(r)
```

My question is:

Does the internal secant method work for complex valued functions?

Comment: the full traceback might help. What is this `p1` that it's comparing to 0?

Comment: @hpaulj I added the last line of the traceback. `p1` is internal to the function `newton` it can be found [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/47bb6febaa10658c72962b9615d5d5aa2513fa3a/scipy/optimize/zeros.py#L325) in the scipy source code.

Comment: Are you using a complex valued function (ie the codomain is complex) or a function with a complex domain?

Comment: @azelcer well in this case it doesn't matter that much since the problem is the comparison between `complex` and `int`. No function evaluation is done prior to this check.

Comment: The ordering of complex values is ill defined (complex is not orderable). Maybe you can trick the optimizer so it starts adding an `abs` or `np.real`:  `p1 += (eps if np.real(p1) >= 0 else -eps)`

Comment: @azelcer good point, I was thinking something amongst the same lines. Using `abs` was what I was thinking. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I ask for the **full** traceback, not an extra line.  But since you looked at the source, code, you can tell us what `p1` is, and why it's being compared to 0.  I realize that a traceback like this will have many layers, but if you want help, someone has to dig through it to see what is happening.  Better you than someone with a 30 second attention span.

Comment: TBH I understood that this method works for complex valued functions with real domains. It seems I am wrong (only if derivatives are provided)

Comment: @hpaulj I figured out what the issue was, long story short `p1` is the second point to the `secant` method and it ends up being a `complex` number since it's derived from the initial condition to the algo which is a `complex` number. There's no >= between `complex` and `int` (expected) thus the error. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: There's no >= between `complex` and `complex`, indeed.

Comment: @azelcer Going back to your point I think if a comparison between the real parts or a lexicographical comparison (compare real parts and if equal then compare the imaginary ones) is used the problem will be solved. Maybe it was meant to be this way but there's nothing in the docs mentioning this corner case. I got away with passing another initial guess and skipping that line. Thanks for your help!